# How to call phtml file in admin block magento 2?

Tags: phtml, footer, copyright

I have created custom theme and I want to call copyright.phtml file in a block I have created on admin side.
I added this

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"template="Magento_Theme::copyright.phtml"}}
```

in my block but it's not working

Comment: did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> {{block class="***Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer***" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"}}

Make sure copyright.phtml file exists in your YOUR_THEME/Magento_Theme directory

Answer (score 1):

This is Right way of calling your phtml file to cms page

```
{{block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"}}
```

or you can override this file in your custom theme

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way of calling phtml in block
Please add space before template

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"template="Magento_Theme::copyright.phtml"}}
```

Or check if your copyright.phtml is existed in your YOUR_THEME/Magento_Theme directry